# TypeScript interface definition type error

Tags: typescript

I got an error in the following definition in typescript, may I know what is the problem?

```
interface Dictionary {
[index: string]: string;
length: number; 
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Dictionary` interface,

```
[index: string]: string;
```

is called a string index signature, and tells the compiler all properties of a `Dictionary` must be of type `string`. You would commonly use an index signature to avoid having an array of mixed types.

So then doing this is OK:

```
let d: Dictionary;
d["foo"] = "bar";
```

But this will give a compiler error:

```
let d: Dictionary;
d["foo"] = 1000;
```

You can define properties for `Dictionary`, as long as every property you define is of type `string`. For example, this is OK:

```
interface Dictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
    foo: string;
}
```

And will allow you to do this:

```
let d: Dictionary;
d.foo = "bar";
```

But in your case, you tried to define a property called `length` as a `number` after you already told the compiler that all properties would be of type `string`. That's why you got a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the TypeScript documentation on [array types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types). All properties must have the same return type so you can't declare length with a return type number on the interface.

To get the length of the array you could cast back to a generic array type:

```
    (<Array<any>>yourArray).length
```